Duplicate traces in FastAPI OpenTelemetry Azure Application Insight
Im currently setting up Otel for our cloud azure solution. We are using Azure WebApp and AzureAppInsights. The app is fastapi backend.
I have set up the otel like:
def setup_otel(app: FastAPI):
    if settings.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING:
        configure_azure_monitor(
            connection_string=settings.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
            logger_name=settings.LOGGER_NAME
        )

The traces for transactions are present in App Insight but the root (probably) fastapi implementation traces are duplicated - POST /api/ingest/v2/upload http receive, more can be seen at screenshot:

Can this be somehow fixed?
Thanks in advance

Check the updated solution below.


Duplicate traces in FastAPI OpenTelemetry Azure Application Insight


To address the issue of duplicate traces in your FastAPI application with OpenTelemetry and Azure Application Insights, Ensure that you're logging and tracing configurations are set up properly.
The FastAPI application is initialized with app = FastAPI(). Ensure that FastAPI's built-in access logging is disabled by default.
The below sample code is used to remove the duplicate traces in application insights.

Code:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.exporter.azuremonitor import AzureMonitorSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.fastapi import FastAPIInstrumentor
from app.settings import settings

def setup_otel(app: FastAPI):
    # Initialize the Azure Monitor Span Exporter
    azure_exporter = AzureMonitorSpanExporter(
        connection_string=settings.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING
    )

    # Create a BatchSpanProcessor and add the exporter to it
    span_processor = BatchSpanProcessor(azure_exporter)

    # Create a Tracer Provider and register the BatchSpanProcessor with it
    trace_provider = TracerProvider()
    trace_provider.add_span_processor(span_processor)

    # Set the Tracer Provider as the global tracer provider
    trace.set_tracer_provider(trace_provider)

    # Instrument FastAPI application
    FastAPIInstrumentor().instrument_app(app)

# Initialize FastAPI app
app = FastAPI()

# Setup OpenTelemetry
setup_otel(app)

@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}



Make sure to install the package pip install opentelemetry-exporter-azuremonitor.

Check initialization of OpenTelemetry and FastAPI, It can help prevent duplicate traces in your Azure Application Insights logs.
Output:


